# Using Core Graphics to draw a separator line on top of standard grouped tableView cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, core-graphics

I can't believe I am asking the classic "How do I draw a line" question, but it is a little more complicated than that.

I have a grouped tableview whose separatorColor I have set to clear. This removes the border and separators. I also have a category on UITableViewCell that I am using to draw some gradients around the cells.

I would like to be able to also draw line separators within this same category. Here is what I have so far:

```
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSaveGState(ctx);

float y = height;

CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, CGRectGetMinX(rect), y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, CGRectGetMaxX(rect), y);

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, color.CGColor);
CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, width);
CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
```

This works, but the line shows up **behind** the tableView cells. I would like for it to be visible on top of the cells.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

EDIT: Screenshot

If you look really closely, you can see green pixels on the edges. The bottom one is completely visible.

EDIT 2: Code

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
     CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
     CGContextSaveGState(ctx);

     [self drawLineSeparator:self.contentView.frame];
}


- (void) drawLineSeparator:(CGRect)rect {
     [self drawLineAtHeight:CGRectGetMaxY(rect)
                  rect:rect
                 color:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:1 blue:0 alpha:.7]
                 width:1];
}


- (void) drawLineAtHeight:(float)height rect:(CGRect)rect color:(UIColor *)color width:(float)width {
     CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
     CGContextSaveGState(ctx);

     float y = height;

     CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, CGRectGetMinX(rect), y);
     CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, CGRectGetMaxX(rect), y);

     CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, color.CGColor);
     CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, width);
     CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

     CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? I'm unclear what behind the cell might look like.

Comment: “I also have a category on UITableViewCell…”  What is the name of the method in this category?  How are you calling it?  Where are you calling it from?

Comment: Posted code. I am totally new to CG, so I may be way off in this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it's a bad idea to override methods of framework classes using a category.  What you have done affects every instance of `UITableViewCell` in your app.  You aren't directly responsible for every table view cell in your app!  For example, a `UIPickerView` has embedded table views, and a `UIDatePicker` has an embedded `UIPickerView`.  So if you use either of those, your category may change their appearance in ways you didn't expect or want.

Instead, create a subclass of `UITableViewCell` and override `drawRect:` in your subclass.

Second, `UITableViewCell` uses a subview to draw its background.  A subview's contents is always “on top of” the superview's contents.  So your green line is underneath the background view's contents.  That's why you can't see it.

One fix is to simply add a one-point-tall, green subview to the cell.  Then you don't have to override `drawRect:` at all.  You can even do it in your cell subclass.  Example:

```
// MyCell.h

@interface MyCell : UITableViewCell
@end

// MyCell.m

#import "MyCell.h"

@implementation MyCell {
    UIView *greenLineView;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self layoutGreenLineSubview];
}

- (void)layoutGreenLineSubview {
    if (!greenLineView) {
        greenLineView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        greenLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        greenLineView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        [self.contentView addSubview:greenLineView];
    }
    CGRect frame = self.contentView.bounds;
    frame.origin.y = CGRectGetMaxY(frame);
    frame.size.height = 1;
    greenLineView.frame = frame;
}

@end
```

Comment: Fantastic! I feel like I just had a major ahaaa moment thanks to your answer. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.